# Split the same virtualhost configuration across multiple files

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

If you have only one large file in `etc/apache/sites-available`, is there a simple solution to split the apache vhost file into separate files so you could use them in the Apache folders `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`?

Answer (score 1):

I created a python scrript that will do the task at github: https://github.com/rubo77/vhost-split.py

It splits an apache vhost file into separate files so you could use them in the Apache folders `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`.

Just pass the configuration file and the script will generate a bunch of files named with the ServerName variable found in each virtual host. Note that repeated entries will generate separate files 
    (http://www.mydomain.com, http://www.mydomain.com-1, …).
Usage:

```
vhost-split.py <config_file>
```